# What is Directional quantile envelopes and its application?

Tags: machine-learning

According to [this website](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/382814), there are a lot of very cool graphs. But when I did research on "Directional quantile envelopes", there are minimum information about it. So I am wondering what exactly it is and how can I apply to data analysis?

Comment: What research have you done?  That page includes a link to a blog page which provides a description, and also references for further reading.  Have you read that?  Do you have any specific questions about what is written there?

Comment: @D.W. yes i did, but the description and references basically describe HOW to make the graph but not why making them

Comment: You asked what exactly it is, and it seems those places have some useful information about that.  Perhaps you might like to [edit] your post to clarify what you are asking?  Also, it might be helpful if you could [edit] your question to share what you've found so far, provide some background, and summarize what you've found so far (e.g., how they are constructed or what they are).  That might make the question more useful for others and more likely to get a good answer.